# error the second time I try to Mint: "execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"

Tags: web3js, transactions, tokens, dapps, polygon

I've a problem trying to mint a token in a custom smart-contract.

I'm using Nextjs and Wagmi to read/write to the contract

```
 const { data, writeAsync: approve } = useErc20Write("approve", [
    tokens["USDC"].address as Address,
    amountIn.toString()
  ]);

  const { data: mintingData, writeAsync: mint } = usePeronioWrite("mint", [
    address as Address,
    amountIn.toString(),
    amountOut.toString()
  ]);
```

The approve is made successfully and the first time the mint worked fine, the decimals for the contract is 6 so im converting to bignumber and adding 6 decimals.

The second time I try to mint this error show up and never go away.

The allowance is fine, I approve 5 more USDC and i make a decreaseAllowance to reset the allowance to 0 but nothing changes.

I already have some other issues implementing this since it's my first time with web3. but in the other issues the mint function executes, its create a hash but its fail to mint the tokens, in this problem the mint function never executes.

This is how I convert the amount into bignumber, I put some slippage there because if I dont put that the trasaction fails.

```
    const slippage = (Number(amountOfPe) * 5) / 100;
  const amountOutBn = new BigNumber((Number(amountOfPe) - slippage).toFixed(3));
  const amountOut = amountOutBn.times(new BigNumber("10").pow(6));
```

if you need more info about the problem, let me know!

Edit: some context about the usage, the custom token use USDC to mint the tokens so, I made a custom hook useERC20Read/write to allowance and approve USDC and usePeronioRead/write to mint the tokens

this is the function that runs mint when user clicked the button

```
const runMint = async () => {
    try {
      if (allowanceLeft > usdcValue) {
        setButtonText("Emitiendo...");
        const response = await mint();
        await decreaseAllowance();
      }

      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error?.message);
      } else {
        notifySuccess(
          `Minteaste ${Number(amountOfPe).toFixed(3)} P por ${usdcValue} USDC.`
        );
      }
      setIsMinted(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsMinted(true);
        setUsdcValue("");
        setButtonText("Emitir");
      }, 500);
    } catch (e: any) {
      setErrorMessage(e.message);
      setIsMinted(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsMinted(true);
        setUsdcValue("");
        setButtonText("Emitir");
      }, 500);
    }
  };
```